# VPN issues Cisco IPSec Mavericks 10.9.3

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, vpn

This is my first post here on AskDifferent. I have a user who can not connect to the VPN on his Mac. It is a MBP 11,1 with a Core i5 2.4GHz 8gb of memory running OS X 10.9.3 . I have had him create a new VPN connection with all of the necessary information and still no dice. No one else in the company who is running Mavericks is having any issue VPNing into the office.

I am at my wits end here. I am typing this on a MacBook Air that is currently on the company VPN.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Cisco VPN Client, the following network ports must be opened in your firewall software:

- 500 UDP
- 4500 UDP
- 10000 UDP

Normally, When you install the Cisco VPN Client, it automatically opens these ports on the firewall. So check whether the user has another software firewall installed on the computer, If so you will need to manually open these ports.

Hope it could help.